# TToolbar Button with dropdown menu greyed out

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I'm having issues getting a TToolbar Button to appear "enable"

The button has an Action assigned to it - which is fire by the OnClick event

It is also setup with a Drop Down Menu, which has 2 options on it, both of which are enabled, and both of which fire off when clicked.

Despite all this the TToolbar Button steadfastly remains greyed out, but accepts the clicks.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing things wrong. :-)

When using actions, you don't use the button's `OnClick` event - you put the code in the action's `OnExecute` event instead (because that's what's executing - the action - and not the button). When an action is assigned to the control, the control cannot be enabled until there's a handler for the `TAction.OnExecute`.

The reason for using actions is so you can put the code in a single place (events related to the action), and then every single control attached to that action uses that common code to perform the same functionality. Editing the code in that single location means all controls attached to that action see the same changes.

If there's nothing attached to the `TAction.OnExecute` event, the control has nothing to do if it was selected (clicked), and so there's no reason to enable it in the first place.

Comment: Also see DisableIfNoHandler.

Comment: The OnClick has been added by Delphi, and is set to the ActionOnExecute procedure.

Comment: @DanKelly: No, the OnClick was added by *you* when you double-clicked it in the Object Inspector, and *you* set it to the ActionOnExecute procedure. (The IDE may have generated some code, but it was as a result of *your* actions.) Again, don't do that. :-) Delete the OnClick handler (just remove the code between the begin..end, leaving a blank line, and remove any var statement, and then compile. Once *you* create an OnClick event for the button, the `ActionOnExecute` is not seen at runtime as being attached to the button, because it has an OnClick event instead.

Comment: @ken-white  I've just tested in Xe6.  1) Add an new Action (Action1) to the Action List.  2) Double Click on the Action in the list.  3) Action1Execute is registered against the OnExecute of tion 1 in the IDE.  4) Add some code.  5) Add a New Button to toolbar.  5) Select Action1 as the new buttons Action.  6) Action1Execute is now listed against Button1.OnClick

Comment: Once again, you're doing it wrong. Start over. Drop the TActionManager on the form, and create an action. Write code in that Action's OnExecute event handler. Add a TActionToolBar, drop the action on it. Nothing on a button OnClick in sight. Oh, got it. You're trying to use the antiquated TToolBar instead of using the TActionToolBar, which is specifically designed to work with the TActionManager.

Comment: When I use a TToolBar, it does in fact assign the Button.OnClick the Action `OnExecute`. I simply added `ShowMessage('Action1 clicked`);` in the `Action1Execute` event, and the toolbar button is properly enabled, and running the app and clicking on the toolbar button shows the message as you'd expect.

Comment: Getting somewhere! I've never used Action Manager or ActionToolBar... 
(I can't see how I'd setup a DropDown button this way)
Standard buttons are fine, it's the dropdown button style that isn't working.  The Menu Items are fine, but the button itself is greyed out.

Comment: Use the property manager for the ActionItem in the Object Inspector. Set the `CommandStyle` property to `csMenu`. Click the `Items` property, then the `...` button. Add new actions for each item you want in the drop down menu to the list of items, like you would any other actions.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else comes across this, I just had this problem (using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo).

For some reason, the "EnableDropdown" property on the TToolButton caused the button to to be greyed out when set to true. Setting this property to false seems to have resolved the problem for me (the dropdown menu remains functional anyway).